# “Except for” vs “aside from”

Tags: phrase-usage

Which of one these makes more grammatical sense?

> The article is free to read, except for what you pay in brain cells.

> The article is free to read, aside from what you pay in brain cells.

Comment: In Australian English I would use the first.

Comment: Could also say _apart from_.